# Difference logistic regressions results in MATLAB vs R

Tags: r, regression, logistic, multiple-regression, matlab

I am trying to run a binomial logistic regression in both R and Matlab. I wanted to use both to confirm that I have same results. However, I cant even get similar results ... What am I missing?

Comment: Can you please post the output? Showing the output and highlight the output is required to answer this question

Comment: It seems that you have removed a lot of information in your most recent editing of this question. Please edit the question to add back all relevant information about the commands your submitted to R and Matlab, and the outputs you received from them. Otherwise the "output" referenced in an answer will not be readily visible to new visitors to the site, making this thread of limited usefulness.

Answer (score 1):

`lme4::glmer` and MATLAB's `fitglme` use different default optimization algorithms (as can be seen from the output):  `lme4::glmer` uses maximum likelihood with Laplace approximation, while MATLAB uses maximum pseudo likelihood as the default. You can adjust the [`FitMethod` parameter in MATLAB](https://mathworks.com/help/stats/fitglme.html#budparz-FitMethod) to see whether you get similar results once you choose a similar optimization algorithm.

A few more resources regarding the different optimization methods:

- https://bbolker.github.io/mixedmodels-misc/glmmFAQ.html (see Estimation)
- https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/glmmsr/vignettes/glmmsr-vignette.pdf